# Select ComboBox First item in DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I want the first item of each combo box to be selected automatically.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Version}" >
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Versions}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>

    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Versions}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>

</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I wrote `<Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />` on **EditingElementStyle** & **ElementStyle** but nothing happened and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set a `SelectedItemBinding` in your XAML, so the selected item is synchronized from your view model and is most likely `null`. If you remove the binding from your data grid combo box column definitions, this setter works.

```
<Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
```

However, the most simple solution is to keep the selected item binding and set the `Version` property in your model to the first item in your collection when you assign or populate it.

```
Version = Versions[0];
```

Then the `ComboBox` will get this item as the selected item and there is no need to add a setter.